# AFNetworking with iOS 8 Loop request in UIAlert

Tags: ios, afnetworking, uialertview, ios8

I have issues with AFNetworking in iOS 8 + UIAlert. in UIAlertView delegate:

```
(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I made HTTP Post request, but it never calls AFNetworking success or failure blocks.

**I see the HTTP Request call into server Log,**

It works in iOS 7.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Bla bla bla",nil)
                          message: NSLocalizedString(@"Bla bla bla",nil)
                          delegate: self
                          cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No",nil)
                          otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Si",nil), nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {        
 if (buttonIndex == 1) {
   [self sendRequest];       
 }
}


- (void) sendRequest {
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"e":@"ecc", @"data": @"ecc2"};
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
   [[manager requestSerializer] setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
   [[manager requestSerializer] setTimeoutInterval:30];
   [manager POST:url parameters:parameters 
               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
// NEVER call block
                        NSLog(@"Request success %@", responseObject);
            }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
// NEVER call block
                      NSLog(@"Error HTTP: %@\n%@", operation, error);
                }];
}
```

Comment: Where's the request code ?

Comment: Did you set the delegate for UIAlertView

Comment: NDA..? I'd ask this on the Developer Forums...

Comment: Since the server receives the request, you should just set breakpoints inside the relevant AFNetworking code to determine what's not working correctly.

Comment: I found the problem: 

In AFURLConnectionOperation
- (void)finish {
    [self.lock lock];
    self.state = AFOperationFinishedState;
    [self.lock unlock];
//ALL OK
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// NEVER CALL
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification object:self];
    });
}

Comment: Did you know that `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in favor of `UIAlertController` in iOS8. See the section for UIKit Framework in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW13 for `"The new UIAlertController class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes as the preferred way to display alerts in your app."`